# Angularjs $httpBackend unexpected request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httpbackend

I am trying to set up a unit test for AngularJS controller which includes a service that calls `$http.get` method. However, even though I use `$httpBackend.expectGET` before `$httpBackend.flush()`, app is trying to 
`GET` template HTML resources, so it gives an unexpected request error.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
        controller = $injector.get('$controller');
        scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
        httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        httpBackend.whenGET(UrlPrefix+"/promotions/default.json").respond("yeh");

    }));

 it("should fetch promotions", function() {

        httpBackend.expectGET(UrlPrefix+"/promotions/default.json") ;


        Controller = controller('promotionsController',{

            $scope : scope

        });

        scope.getPromotions();
        httpBackend.flush();
    });
});
```

I am getting:

> Unexpected request : GET ./template/loader/app-loader.html

This is my template that should be loaded before the controller. Do you have any idea how to bypass template GETS?

Comment: Can you show the `getPromotions()` method you are testing?  What is loading the template in that method?

Comment: Is it possible to prevent directive from downloading

Answer (score 0):

If having a real HTML template is not important for this specific test, you can prevent it from being downloaded by populating `$templateCache` with some dummy template. Something like this

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $templateCache) {
    // ...
    $templateCache.put('./template/loader/app-loader.html', '');
}));
```

You may probably need to adjust template url to match real one being requested.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. It still gives the same error. It felt like it would work though, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Are you sure urls match?

Comment: Well angular adds ?NoCache = 1230123819 parameter to it. So practically they are not the same. However that number is created without my control.

Comment: Angular should not load template if the the one with corresponding URL is already is stored in cache. If it's not there then angular issues new request. `NoCache` parameter doesn't sound like Angular related though.

Comment: You are right about the NoCache matter. It was related to the project I am working on. However the templatecaching still does not work. What I reallly do not understand it that how can $httpBackend has such a property. It makes it unusable. I dont think angularjs intends it to be this way. I ran into similar problems in stackoverflow, and those people forgot to put expectGET. In my case, it was always there and does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know I think you should bypass it

```
 $httpBackend.whenGET('./template/loader/app-loader.html').passThrough();
```